# Div's width decreases when show slide animation is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress-theming

When my card title is clicked, its content shows or hides with the show slide jquery animation `.show('slide', {direction: 'up'}, 'slow')` / `.hide('slide', {direction: 'up'}, 'slow'`. The problem is that **during the animation the width of `.content-annales` decreases** so there is a lack of continuity with the `.title-annales` div on the right side.

Here is an example of the problem: [click here](https://i.gyazo.com/33f9192ac7a957c2888be70cfdd6bf76.mp4)

```js
jQuery(".title-annales").on("click", function() {
  var element = jQuery(this);
  if (jQuery(this).next().css('display') === 'none') {
    element.css('border-radius', '20px 20px 0px 0px');
    jQuery(this).next().show('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 'slow', function() {
      element.find('.span-msg-mediadroit-annale').html('<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>');
    });

  } else {
    jQuery(this).next().hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 'slow', function() {
      element.css('border-radius', '20px');
      element.find('.span-msg-mediadroit-annale').html('<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="card-annales">
  <div class="title-annales">
    <span class="span-msg-mediadroit-annale float-right"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></span>
    <h3 style="font-size: inherit; display: contents; font-weight: inherit;">Nom matière</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content-annales">
    [...]
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT :** I've tried to replicate the issue on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/louisd67/6dz5k7wg/) but it works perfectly here. I use a bootstrap based theme ([Hestia](https://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Hestia) for Wordpress) and when I remove from the bootstrap css file the property `box-sizing: border-box;`, it works like in the jsfiddle.

Comment: snippet not run well

Comment: Yes actually. I created a jsfiddle in the edit.

Comment: can you provide website link ? 
or a code which is not working properly

Comment: @KareemDabbeet Unfortunately I can't do this. But I solved my issue (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally fixed the issue.

**1. Probable cause of the issue**

When `.show('slide', { direction: 'up'}, 'slow')` is executed, jquery-ui sets a fixed width to the selected div which seems to not take into consideration the padding (`padding: 10px` for `.content-annales`). *See what happened during the jquery animation*: [image: jquery animation]
I don't really understand why the padding is not taked into account as it works perfectly in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/louisd67/6dz5k7wg/) shared in my question. It could be link to `box-sizing: border-box;` which is set for all html according to my theme. In fact, when I disable it, the issue disappear.

**2. My solution**

It's quite simple : I've encapsulated `.content-annales` in a parent div called `.content-annales-toggle` which has no style except `display: none;`. My animation now shows/hides up `.content-annales-toggle` so there is no issue with the padding.

Here is the new code :

```js
jQuery(".title-annales").on("click", function() {
  var element = jQuery(this);
  if (jQuery(this).next().css('display') === 'none') {
    element.css('border-radius', '20px 20px 0px 0px');
    jQuery(this).next().show('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 'slow', function() {
      element.find('.span-msg-mediadroit-annale').html('<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>');
    });

  } else {
    jQuery(this).next().hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 'slow', function() {
      element.css('border-radius', '20px');
      element.find('.span-msg-mediadroit-annale').html('<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<style>
.card-annales {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.title-annales {
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px;
    background-color: #012f51;
    color: #ff6501;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    border: gray 1px solid;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content-annales-toggle {
display: none; /* edited */
}
.content-annales {
    border-left: gray 1px solid;
    border-right: gray 1px solid;
    border-bottom: gray 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
    display: block; /* edited */

}
.float-right {
float: right;
}
.float-left {
float: left;
}
</style>
 <div class="card-annales">
  <div class="title-annales">
    <span class="span-msg-mediadroit-annale float-right"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></span>
    <h3 style="font-size: inherit; display: contents; font-weight: inherit;">Nom matière</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content-annales-toggle">
      <div class="content-annales">
        [...]
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to reproduce the behavior that you mentioned, but have a possible solution for you. Add `width: calc(100% - 20px);` to `.content-annales`.

```js
jQuery(".title-annales").on("click", function() {
  var element = jQuery(this);
  if (jQuery(this).next().css('display') === 'none') {
    element.css('border-radius', '20px 20px 0px 0px');
    jQuery(this).next().show('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 'slow', function() {
      element.find('.span-msg-mediadroit-annale').html('<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>');
    });

  } else {
    jQuery(this).next().hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 'slow', function() {
      element.css('border-radius', '20px');
      element.find('.span-msg-mediadroit-annale').html('<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.card-annales {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.title-annales {
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px;
  background-color: #012f51;
  color: #ff6501;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-annales {
  border-left: gray 1px solid;
  border-right: gray 1px solid;
  border-bottom: gray 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  display: none;
  width: calc(100% - 20px); /* added */
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-annales">
  <div class="title-annales">
    <span class="span-msg-mediadroit-annale float-right"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></span>
    <h3 style="font-size: inherit; display: contents; font-weight: inherit;">Nom matière</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content-annales">
    [...]
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work but you helped me a lot to understand that the problem came from the 20px caused by the padding set for `.content-annales` (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to overflow when the content is rendered. Consider the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zqk9johc/

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(".title-annales").on("click", function() {
  var element = jQuery(this);
  var nextEl = element.next();
  var parentEl = element.parent();
  var iconUp = $("<i>", {
    class: "fas fa-chevron-circle-up"
  });
  var iconDown = $("<i>", {
    class: "fas fa-chevron-circle-up"
  });
  if (nextEl.css('display') === 'none') {
    nextEl.show('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 'slow', function() {
      element.css('border-radius', '20px 20px 0px 0px');
      jQuery('.span-msg-mediadroit-annale', element).html(iconUp);
    });
  } else {
    nextEl.hide('slide', {
      direction: 'up'
    }, 'slow', function() {
      element.css('border-radius', '20px');
      jQuery('.span-msg-mediadroit-annale', element).html(iconDown);
    });
  }
});
```

Nothing vastly different in the code, yet in the Fiddle I have added 5 paragraphs. When the content is shown, a scroll bar is rendered by the browser as the content extends beyond the current window height. The scroll bar being rendered seems to re-flow the content of the document.

If you add some CSS:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

The Scroll Bar is already rendered and no re-flow is needed.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zqk9johc/5/

Comment: Thx for your answer. I was thinking the same but adding `overflow-y: scroll;` changes nothing. I've even tried by setting `overflow-y: hidden;`. The following jsfiddle points out the fact that the scrollbar seems to not be the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/louisd67/873sLrpn/.

Answer (score -1):

Please remove the padding from the class "content-annales" and wrap inner content on div and adding padding to the same.

Please check the code below:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-annales">
  <div class="title-annales">
    <span class="span-msg-mediadroit-annale float-right"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></span>
    <h3 style="font-size: inherit; display: contents; font-weight: inherit;">Nom matière</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content-annales">
    <div class="inner-section">
        [...]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>

.card-annales {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.title-annales {
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px;
  background-color: #012f51;
  color: #ff6501;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-annales {
  border-left: gray 1px solid;
  border-right: gray 1px solid;
  border-bottom: gray 1px solid;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  display: none;
}

.inner-section {
  padding: 10px;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

</style>

<script>

    jQuery(".title-annales").on("click", function() {
      var element = jQuery(this);
      if (jQuery(this).next().css('display') === 'none') {
        element.css('border-radius', '20px 20px 0px 0px');
        jQuery(this).next().show('slide', {
          direction: 'up'
        }, 'slow', function() {
          element.find('.span-msg-mediadroit-annale').html('<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>');
        });

      } else {
        jQuery(this).next().hide('slide', {
          direction: 'up'
        }, 'slow', function() {
          element.css('border-radius', '20px');
          element.find('.span-msg-mediadroit-annale').html('<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>');
        });
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I've exposed in my answer dated of July, the 20th. Pls see below.